# Vertically center div with Bootstrap and IE fix

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, center

Currently, I am using this html and CSS which works great in Chrome, Firefox and safari.

[image: Login html rendering view]

However, it ***doesn't*** even work in **IE9 and IE10** ( we are not trying to support IE8 or any previous versions).

In internet explorer 10 it looks like this. Centered horizontally , however it is not centered vertically.
[image]

```css
.login-page-container {
  min-height: 293px;
  min-height: 29.3rem;
  min-width: 328px;
  min-width: 32.8rem;
  background-color: red;
}

.vertical-center {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.relative-position {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical-center relative-position">
  <div class="login-page-container">
    <div class="page-header">
      <div class="login-header center-block">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <form action="/Account/Login" class="" method="post" role="form">
          <div class="login-form-container">
                <!-- elements -->
            <h1>Element </h1>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So any help will be appreciated. Thank you advance.

Answer (score 0):

for IE9 and IE10 put display:table
and set attribute vallign="middle"

vallign is a basic property supperted by old browsers as well as some new browsers

Comment: valign="center" is attribute for td. I dont think it is available for div

Comment: you can use it when you will use display:table to parent and display:table cell to child

Comment: Let me give it a try.

Comment: it should be css attribute vertical-align: middle;.. also there is no value center for valign. its 'middle'

Comment: yup, it is middle, and when I come to use of these type of behavior I use table in stead of div for cross browser compatibility.

Comment: @AkhileshKumar where should I add this class. In the .vertical-center or .login-page-container